# Equivariant version of cyclic versus de Rham (co)homology of commutative algebras?

Tags: equivariant-cohomology, cyclic-homology

Let $A$ be a commutative algebra that is a $g$-module, for some Abelian Lie algebra $g$. The primary example of my interest is when $A$ is the ring of functions over an affine variety, say $\mathbb{C}^n$. There is a standard relation that expresses the cyclic cohomology ${\rm HC}^k(A)$ in terms of the direct sum of the kernel of the transpose of de Rham differential on $(\Omega^k)^*$ (the space of $k$-currents), and successive de Rham homology groups of $A$ of degree $k-2, k-4$, etc. In the case where $A$ is the polynomial ring over $\mathbb{C}^n$ these de Rham homology groups are trivial except in degree 0 case. Now my question is, is there a $g$-equivariant version of this statement? Namely, does the relation between cyclic cohomology and de Rham homology still hold if I replace both sides by their $g$-equivariant versions?

Comment: do you have a reference for the relation you are mentionning? Thanks!